# svg use tag in jquery not returning self closing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Consider the following html code:

```
<a id="generic" href="#">
    <svg class=""><use xlink:href="#icon-menu" /></svg>
</a>
```

And consider the following js:

```
$('#generic').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

I would expect the output of alert to be `<svg class=""><use xlink:href="#icon-menu" /></svg>`, in other words, an `<svg>` with a self-closing `<use />` tag as I used.

However, the js returns not a self-closing `<use />` tag, rather, it converts it to a closing `<use>` tag.

This is the output: `<svg class=""><use xlink:href="#icon-menu"></use></svg>`.

Any reason why it ignores my self-closing `<use />` tag and converts it to a closing `<use></use>` tag?

Comment: Those forms are exactly the same semantically. Why worry about it? It's just an artifact of the serialization process.

Comment: Well, semantically I wasn't worrying. Except I noticed the "issue" if you will when I was checking an if statement in js to verify the .html content of that element. I was checking using the self closing tag and it was failing the check, even though, as you said, semantically they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser parses the HTML into DOM form internally and doesn't keep a record of whether you used an end tag or a self-closing tag.  Self closing tags are just a convenience for authors.  You could think of it as compiled code.

When the internal DOM representation is then serialized out again when you do `html()`, or the DOM method `.innerHTML()`, the browser just outputs the standard long form.